# VB.NET Argument Prompt cannot be converted to type string

Tags: vb.net

I'm made a new list of string and when I try to add something there it gives me an error: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'string

My code:

```
Dim variables As New List(Of String)
Try
            variables.Append(CStr(TextBox1.Text))
            variables.Append(CStr(TextBox2.Text))
            MsgBox(variables)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What's the point of converting a `String` to a `String`? You use `CStr` to convert or cast something to or as type `String`. The `Text` property of a control is already type `String` so what are you achieving?

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from your use of `MsgBox()`.  You're passing it the `variables` variable, and it doesn't know how to convert a `List(Of String)` to a `String`.

As stated by jmcilhinney, you should be using `Add()` instead of `Append()`.

Additionally, you should use `MessageBox.Show()` instead of `MsgBox()`.

As for the error, we can only assume you want to see all the current values in your List?  If so, one solution is to use `String.Join()` and display that instead:

```
Dim variables As New List(Of String)
variables.Add(TextBox1.Text)
variables.Add(TextBox2.Text)
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", variables))
```

But your `variables` list should be declared at Form level so that you aren't creating a new one each time.  It isn't clear from your post if this is the case or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling the `Add` instance method of your `List(Of String)`. `Append` is an extension method and is not appropriate in that scenario. `Append` would be used for an enumerable list that you wanted to enumerate on the spot, e.g.

```vb
Dim names = {"Peter", "Paul", "Mary"}
Dim pNames = names.Where(Function(name) name.StartsWith("P"))

For Each pName In pNames.Append("Philip")
    Console.WriteLine(pName)
Next
```

In that case the `Append` only affects the list being enumerated by the loop where it's used. The original list is unaffected.

Comment: If it didn't work then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did then we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @jmcihinney im trying to make a way to make dynamically variables

Comment: It doesn't really matter what your motivation is. You asked how to do something specific and I told you how to do it. If you do what I said then the code you have will work, at least  as far as adding the specified items to that list. If you have a different question maybe you should post that question instead of tagging it on in a comment on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `Add` method:

```
Dim variables As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
variables.Add(TextBox1.Text)
```

(No need for the redundant `CStr` as `TextBox1.Text` is already of type `String`.)

As @Mary will no doubt suggest - rightly! - always have `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` set to *On* (and in my opinion `Option Infer` *Off*); it'll help you with any syntax issues.

And always pay attention to the syntax/compiler suggestions in the left margin which will give you clues/tips to fix or improve your code.

Lastly, refer to the Microsoft documentation if in doubt. It should be your first port-of-call if you're unsure of anything.

Answer (score 0):

As several people have mentioned, use the .Add method not .Append.

The .Text property of a TextBox is already a String. No need to convert with CStr().

A message box displays a String. variables is not a String; it is a List(Of String). To see what is in your list use a For Each loop.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    Dim variables As New List(Of String)
    variables.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    variables.Add(TextBox2.Text)
    For Each s In variables
        MsgBox(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

@SteveCinq is correct :-); turn on Option Strict.